# how to get values into excel sheet from different methods by declaring an global array in python 2.7.13 using scrapy?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

```
import requests
import win32api
import scrapy
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request
from array import *
import itertools
import numpy


class firstSpider(BaseSpider):
      name = "vdfgedu"
      allowed_domains = ["de.vdfg.edu"]
      start_urls = ["https://de.vdfg.edu/nephrology/node/1608"]
      globalarray = []
      def parse(self, response):
      #find all the hrefs first
          depts_with_info = []
          for dept_info in response.css('div.pane-content'):
                   depts = {}
                   links = dept_info.css('table.views-table tbody tr.viewsrow-first td a::attr(href)').extract()
                   for link in links:
                           yield scrapy.Request("https://de.vdfg.edu"+link, callback = self.title_info)
                           yield scrapy.Request("https://de.vdfg.edu"+link+"#group-tabs-node-course-default3", callback = self.venue_info)
                   def title_info(self, response):
                         titleinfo = {}
                         titleinfo['title'] = response.css('div.field-item h1::text').extract()
                         titleinfo['cmepoints'] = response.css('div.item-list ul.course-credit-list li span::text').extract()[0].strip()
                        self.globalarray.append(titleinfo)
                  def venue_info(self, response):
                       venueinfo = {}
                       venueinfo['venue'] = response.css('div.adr span::text').extract()
                       self.globalarray.append(venueinfo)
```

how to append values from these two methods title_info, venue_info to an single array...to extract into excel sheet with respective hrefs...i applied above code..but getting o/p like this : ScrapyDeprecationWarning: vdfgclinic.spiders.mayos.firstSpider inherits from deprecated class scrapy.spiders.BaseSpider, please inherit from scrapy.spiders.Spider. (warning only on first subclass, there may be others).......

Filtered duplicate request: https://de.vdfg.edu/nephrology/content/16th-annual-vdfg-clinic-update-nephrology-and-transplantation-2018#group-tabs-node-course-default3> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2017-10-14 17:08:45 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://de.vdfg.edu/nephrology/content/16th-annual-vdfg-clinic-update-nephrology-and-transplantation-2018> (referer: https://de.vdfg.edu/nephrology/node/1608)..

Comment: Is this for homework or your job? You  seem to have asked several very similar questions about this.

Comment: sorry, I don't know python.

Comment: can any one answer above question please!